# What should a celibate do ,to attain moksha ,only by maintaining unbroken celibacy?

Tags: moksha, siddhi, sadhana, brahmacharya, ojas

[This video attributes a quite to Swami Shivananda](https://youtu.be/s8XQW4C-_hA),saying that practice of unbroken celibacy for 12 years,will be sufficient for the practioner such that he will undergo Self Realization,when he hears the Mahavakya once.

Is this true?

Since merely retaining semen and not thinking sexually(I have heard that action is our thoughts in a gross form),can be practised by anyone,(probably even an atheist,or someone without a Guru as well)(like Dr. APJ Kalam,for example) what more should a person do such that he is able to maintain this kind of a level?